# How can I use a function as argument to a member function?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I am trying to use the member function Sover::tov as an argument to another function using std::bind. I get a compile error at calling std::bind. Briefly, the essence of my code is the following. What is wrong with my syntax or is there a better way to do what I want?

```
class Solver {
   private:
      ....
   public:
    ....
       double solve(vector< vector<double> > & sol, const double &z, const double &n) 
        {...
            method(std::bind(&Solver::tov, *this, pl::_1 , pl::_2 , pl::_3 ),y,x,dx)
         ...}
        void tov ( const vector<double> &y, vector<double> &dy, const double &x ) {...}
   };     
void method(void (*i_function)(const vector< double > &, vector<double> &, const double &), vector< double > &y, const double &x, const double &h) {...}
```

Let me give a concrete example that reproduces my main problem:

```
void method(void (*i_function)(double &), double &y) { i_function(y); }

 class Solver
{
     public: 
         Solver() {}
         void solve(double &y) {    method(do_calc,y); }
         void do_calc(double &x)    { x += 1; }
 };

 int main() 
 {
    double y = 1;
    Solver().solve(y);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
 }
```

which gives the error: 
error: cannot convert ‘Solver::do_calc’ from type ‘void (Solver::)(double&)’ to type ‘void (*)(double&)’
   void solve(double &y) { method(do_calc,y); }

Even if I use

```
 void method(std::function<void(double &)> i_function, double &y) { i_function(y); }
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: The result of `std::bind` is not convertible to a function pointer

Comment: The brief essence of your code is that you have a bunch of syntax errors in there. Seriously, extract a minimal example and format it properly and consistently.

Comment: You probably want to use std::function instead of a function pointer.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! Dear @UlrichEckhardt you are right I should have given an exact example. Now, I have updated the question with one.

Comment: Use the `std::function<void(double &)>` version and then `method(std::bind(&Solver::do_calc, this, std::placeholders::_1), y);`, or `method([this](double& x){do_calc(x);}, y);`, or leave the function pointer version but make the `do_calc` function a `static` one and call it like so `method(&Solver::do_calc, y);`

Comment: @Piotr OMG. _Stop_ writing answers as comments FFS.